# FacebookSDK Integration into Android in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am adding Share to FB feature to my app. I've downloaded the SDK and imported the facebook directory as a module into my project. I've updated settings.gradle as shown below:

```
include ':facebook'
include ':SwipeMenuListView'
include ':FloomIt'
```

and I've updated the app specific build.gradle as shown below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.floomit.floomit"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    multiDexEnabled = true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}


packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
}
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.0.0'
    // compile 'com.aviary.android.feather.sdk:aviary-sdk:3.6.3'
    // compile project(':showcaseView')
    compile project(':facebook')
    // compile project(':mediarouter')
    // compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0'
    compile project(':SwipeMenuListView')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:7.5.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.3'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile files('libs/tape-1.1.0.jar')
}
```

both files just have one extra "facebook" line

When I try building the project, without adding ANY facebook SDK specific code, the build fails with the following errors: (if I remove facebook entries from the build.gradle and settings.gradle, then the build succeeds)

```
:FloomIt:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:FloomIt:compileDebugSources
:FloomIt:collectDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:FloomIt:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex
:FloomIt:shrinkDebugMultiDexComponents
:FloomIt:createDebugMainDexClassList
:FloomIt:dexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:577)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.dex.file.StringIdsSection.intern(StringIdsSection.java:134)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.dex.file.StringIdsSection.intern(StringIdsSection.java:111)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.dex.file.MemberIdItem.addContents(MemberIdItem.java:56)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.dex.file.FieldIdItem.addContents(FieldIdItem.java:43)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.dex.file.UniformItemSection.prepare0(UniformItemSection.java:75)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.dex.file.Section.prepare(Section.java:213)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.toDex0(DexFile.java:505)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.toDex(DexFile.java:214)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.writeDex(Main.java:813)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.createDexFile(Main.java:576)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:721)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:505)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:334)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:244)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","sources":[{}]}


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':FloomIt:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

Can someone suggest how to proceed

Comment: can [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/r4p-sBLl7DQ) help?

Comment: why download? why not simply 'compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0'' ?

Comment: @calvinfly this solved my problem, can you make your comment as an answer and post these lines as the solution, so I can mark it as an accepted answer.   dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding Facebook as a module, it's better to add

```
dependencies {
             compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0'
}
```

in *build.gradle*

Comment: I originally had the dependency as you are suggesting and had the same issue. Importing it as a module was an attempt to see if the problem would go away.